# Apt-get for Open Solaris

Tags: opensolaris

Does Open Solaris have central software repo Ubuntu? What kind of software can be used to fetch package from that repo and install into my machine?

Comment: Hmm, I read that Open Solaris 11 should have IPS (pkg). But my Joyent Machine doesn't seem to have that tool. #$%

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the actual OpenSolaris distro (i.e. `cat /etc/release` says "OpenSolaris 2009.06" or a similar version)
then it does have a central package repository at http://pkg.opensolaris.org/ and 
"pkg install" or the package gui can be used to install new packages.   Documentation of how to use it is available in the [OpenSolaris 2009.06 Image Packaging System Guide](http://dlc.sun.com/osol/docs/content/2009.06/IMGPACKAGESYS/), as well as all over opensolaris.org forums & mailing lists.

Other distros based on OpenSolaris have their own packaging systems, such as apt in Nexenta.

Joyent doesn't actually run the OpenSolaris distro, but their own custom variant of the now-discontinued Solaris Express Community Edition distro - I believe they provide their own package repositories for their users, but I don't know the details.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Nexenta](http://www.nexenta.org/).  It's debian userland on top of the opensolaris kernel, so it includes apt.